# How can I export Apache Solr settings?

Tags: search, features, strongarm

I selected entity types and bundles in admin/config/search/apachesolr. So is there any way to featurize or export these settings? If it can be done by [Strongram](https://www.drupal.org/project/strongarm) module which variable I should use?